# Remove html string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string, removeall

I have a peice of HTML that is being dynamically created from who knows where. Instead of tracking it down can I just run some jQuery to remove it? I want to delete all instances of:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: I would be careful removing that.  You generally see that when you have elements with `float:left` or `float:right`. It allows the parent element of those floats to dynamically grow with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider something like this:

```
$('div[style*=both]').remove();
```

Comment: This seems like what I'd need but I can't get it to work: 

<div style="float:left;">
    Hello 
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div style="float:left;">
    Hello
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#body div[style*=clear:both]').remove();
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").remove();
```

The above will remove all divs.

You might want to provide some more context, to limit the removal to this particular div though.

Comment: I would however attempt where the div originates from though since this is basically sweeping an unknown problem under the rug

Comment: Another consideration is that removing a "clear:both" element might have visual side effects if other elements are floating